# Android: Determine Application Usage

Tags: java, android, battery

I'm working on a project (or will be, if this is possible), and one of the key things I need to do is determine application usage. That is, what application are being used most often, and for the longest amount of time.

I have searched long and hard for a way to directly do this, and have come up with nothing. I know that things like Spare Parts achieve it by using private APIs, but obviously that doesn't help me. Can anyone recommend some effective way to gather the data I need, or another way in which to determine the things I need to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run [powertop](http://www.linuxpowertop.org/) on Android machines? It's an awesome tool, but it may require infrastructure not supported in default kernel builds.

Less directly related to *power*, but still capable of giving you full-system information is [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/). It too might require infrastructure not supported in default kernel builds, but it can show full-system profiling information.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add instrumentation to your own application that keeps track of the time in each activity.  There is no API for this in the platform.